# Firefox 4 isn't firing dragleave or dragexit when a drag leaves the window

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I can't get the dragleave or dragexit events to fire when a drag leaves the window (Firefox4). In Chrome and Safari, this works as expected.... you get a dragleave event when the drag leaves the window.

Is this expected behavior? Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: What are your listeners on? `document` or `window`? If your listeners are on `window`, it *shouldn't* fire those events.

Comment: My listeners are on a fixed position div that fills the document (position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0)

Comment: I filed a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656164

Comment: I have a similar case with a full-screen overlay (for user education).  Firefox will not send any dragleave/dragexit events to window, document, or the overlay element.  The only workaround I have at this point is a timeout after the last mousemove.

Comment: I've seconded your bug report. Annoying.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253663/how-to-detect-the-dragleave-event-in-firefox-when-dragging-outside-the-window

Answer (score 0):

So, to sum up the comments: This is a [browser bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656164), it is still present apparently, and there is a jQuery-based [workaround](https://gist.github.com/3794126).