# Firefox firing dragleave when dragging over text

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm attempting to track a dragenter/leave for the entire screen, which is so far working fine in Chrome/Safari, courtesy of the draghover plugin from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310815/698289 as in:

```
$.fn.draghover = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {

        var collection = $(),
            self = $(this);

        self.on('dragenter', function(e) {
            if (collection.size() === 0) {
                self.trigger('draghoverstart');
            }
            collection = collection.add(e.target);
        });

        self.on('dragleave drop', function(e) {
            // timeout is needed because Firefox 3.6 fires the dragleave event on
            // the previous element before firing dragenter on the next one
            setTimeout( function() {
                collection = collection.not(e.target);
                if (collection.size() === 0) {
                    self.trigger('draghoverend');
                }
            }, 1);
        });
    });
};

function setText(text) {
    $('p.target').text(text);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).draghover().on({
        'draghoverstart': function() {
            setText('enter');
        },
        'draghoverend': function() {
            setText('leave');
        }
    });
});
```

However Firefox is still giving me problems when I drag over text items, here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/tusRy/6/

Is this a Firefox bug or can this be tamed with JS? Or is there a more robust method for performing all of this?

Thanks!

*UPDATE*: Updated fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/tusRy/6/ to reduce clutter a bit. To explain the expected behavior of the fiddle:

- Drag a file into the window and p.target should be "ENTER" colored yellow.
- Drag a file out of the window and p.target should be "LEAVE" colored red.
- Drop a file in the window and p.target should be "LEAVE" colored red.

In firefox, the LEAVE event is triggered when you drag the file over text.

Comment: I have worked around this for now by using an overlay div, as per http://jsfiddle.net/tusRy/7/ however I'm not really happy about this being THE solution so I'll leave this question open until a better idea comes along.

Answer (score 10):

As of version 22.0 Firefox is still doing this. When you drag over a text node it fires two kinds of `dragenter` and `dragleave` events: one where the event target and relatedTarget are BOTH the parent element of the text node, and another where the target is the parent element and the relatedTarget is the actual text node (not even a proper DOM element).

The workaround is just to check for those two kinds of events in your `dragenter` and `dragleave` handlers and ignore them:

```
try {
    if(event.relatedTarget.nodeType == 3) return;
} catch(err) {}
if(event.target === event.relatedTarget) return;
```

I use a try/catch block to check the nodeType because occasionally events fire (inexplicably) from outside the document (eg. in other iframes) and trying to access their nodeType throws a permissions error.

Here's the implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/9A7te/

Comment: I believe there is an issue with jQuery-2.1.1's event handling for dragenter and dragleave: I have noticed that instead of reporting the offending text node as the event.target on dragenter and dragleave, it is passing the text node's parent element instead. If you're still noticing issues I wonder if going native here might help.

Comment: by the way this answer helped me the most. And in case my answer above wasn't very clear: I meant that within this bug, jQuery itself is inaccurately copying event targets over to it's custom Event object. i've implemented a nodeType check based off of event.originalEvent.target and event.originalEvent.relatedTarget with good results

Comment: Works perfect! I added it to the plugin itself to avoid having to re-write it in the end event handler. Works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. Have not tested in other browsers to verify any goofy bugs, but these are the only two main browsers I have to support typically.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with kind of a solution, yet to test on other browsers other than Chrome and FF but working so far. This is how the `setTimeout` looks now:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    var isChild = false;

    // in order to get permission errors, use the try-catch
    // to check if the relatedTarget is a child of the body
    try {
        isChild = $('body').find(e.relatedTarget).length ? true : isChild;
    }
    catch(err){} // do nothing

    collection = collection.not(e.target);
    if (collection.size() === 0 && !isChild) {
        self.trigger('draghoverend');
    }
}, 1);
```

The entire code here - http://jsfiddle.net/tusRy/13/.

The idea is to check if the related tag is a child of the body, in which case we are still in the Browsers and the `draghoverend` event should be not triggered. As this can throw errors when moving out of the windows, I used a try method to avoid it.

Well, perhaps somebody with more skills on JS could improve this :)

Answer (score 2):

1) Your dropzone should have only one child element, which might have everything else you need. Something like

```
<div id="#dropzone">
    <div><!--Your contents here--></div>
</div>
```

2) Use this CSS:

```
#dropzone * { pointer-events: none; }
```

You might need to include the `:before` and `:after` since the `*` don't apply to them.

This should be enough to let the drop work in Firefox and Chrome. In your example, it should be enough to add:

```
body * { pointer-events: none; }
```

At the end of the CSS. I've done it here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/eKttq/

Other examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/6yZV6/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/yR8t8/

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in a non-selected answer to this SO question asking about [dragleave firing on child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867506/dragleave-of-parent-element-fires-when-dragging-over-children-elements).  I have a `<div>` that has many children elements.  An semi-opaque overlay `<span>` becomes visible over the `<div>` whenever there's a `dragenter` on the page.  As you found, 'dragover' isn't like `mouseover`. It triggers `dragleave` whenever you hover over a child element.

The solution?  [Dragout](https://github.com/dancork/jquery.event.dragout)  It makes `dragover` work more like `mouseover`.  Very short.