# javascript drag and drop: detect if dropped outside of window

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have two lists of items - each list in a separate browser window. I have Drag n Drop working between them - which lets me move the items between the windows. Sometimes I just move the items within the same window.

When moving an item from window A to window B I want both windows to refresh to reflect the change. A uses the Drop event and B uses the DragEnd event. However when dragging within the same window I don't want to fire two refresh events on the same page.

It would be nifty to detect that the drop happened outside of its own browser window. How do I do that?

Ps. I've just seen [How to detect the dragleave event in Firefox when dragging outside the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253663/how-to-detect-the-dragleave-event-in-firefox-when-dragging-outside-the-window) but I'd rather see a more simple approach.

Comment: Not sure if what you want to achieve is really possible... Though what have you tried thus far? Post some code... Read the FAQ of this site to see why this is important (and indeed expected of you)

Comment: instead of refreshing the page, why don't you just add and remove the DOM objects in the lists?

Comment: I'm refreshing instead of modifying the DOM since the HTML is generated server side - yes a constraint.
I've tried looking at the only DND event I really get when doing a drag and drop outside of the window - the dragEnd. I can see whether the drag was completed or cancelled. But it's hard to figure out if it was dropped outside of the window.

Comment: Any solution to this by now?

Comment: Hi - were you able to figure out a way to detect if the drop occured outside the window?